# output from bert gives str not tensor in forward function

Tags: python, function, model, bert-language-model

```
class BertModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,pre_trained='bert-base-uncased'):
        super().__init__()        
        self.bert = AutoModel.from_pretrained(pre_trained)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(0.1)
        self.relu =  nn.ReLU()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(768,512)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(512,6)
      
    
        
    def forward(self,inputs, mask, labels):
        
        pooled, cls_hs = self.bert(input_ids=inputs,attention_mask=mask)
        print(pooled)
        print(cls_hs)  
        print(inputs) 
        print(mask)   
        x = self.fc1(cls_hs)
        print(1) 
        x = self.relu(x)
        print(2) 
        x = self.dropout(x)
        print(3) 
      # output layer
        x = self.fc2(x)
        print(4)
      # apply softmax activation
        x = self.softmax(x)
        print(5)
```

> last_hidden_state
> pooler_output

> tensor([[  101,  2342,  2393,  ...,     0,     0,     0],
> [  101, 14477,  4779,  ...,  4839,  6513,   102],
> [  101, 14777,  2111,  ..., 13677,  3613,   102],
> ...,
> [  101,  2113, 14047,  ...,     0,     0,     0],
> [  101,  5683,  3008,  ...,     0,     0,     0],
> [  101, 19046,  2075,  ...,  2050,  3308,   102]])
> tensor([[1, 1, 1,  ..., 0, 0, 0],
> [1, 1, 1,  ..., 1, 1, 1],
> [1, 1, 1,  ..., 1, 1, 1],
> ...,
> [1, 1, 1,  ..., 0, 0, 0],
> [1, 1, 1,  ..., 0, 0, 0],
> [1, 1, 1,  ..., 1, 1, 1]])

in linear(input, weight, bias)
if has_torch_function_variadic(input, weight, bias):
return handle_torch_function(linear, (input, weight, bias), input, weight,
bias=bias)
return torch._C._nn.linear(input, weight, bias)

TypeError: linear(): argument 'input' (position 1) must be Tensor, not str

> pooled, cls_hs printed as string last_hidden_state, pooler_output tensor
> with out any tensor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace the line where you downloaded the pretrained bert model with:

```
self.model = AutoModel.from_pretrained(pre_trained, return_dict=False)
```